# Setting up configuration file for external python interpreter using Visual studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, configuration, interpreter

I have set up an external interpreter manually by using `python.pythonPath: ${env:PYTHON_VAR}`. The external Interpreter is from an application that requires some configuration settings such as server, username and password that have to be set when you call the *exe* via the command line.

Is there a way that I can store the Configuration information for the interpreter in visual studio to automatically apply them each time I run a python file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't any way to specify interpreter commands to use on every execution of the interpreter. I believe there is a feature request for such functionality at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python, but if there isn't you can open a new feature request.